# What's wrong with this JavaScript object literal assignment?

Tags: javascript, netbeans

Perhaps I'm just being dense, but I don't understand why Netbeans is telling me this is bad syntax:

```
var events = {
    'onkeyup'  : 0,
    'onchange' : 0,
    'onclick'  : 0
};
```

Lines 2-4 are squiggled red.

Comment: They look ok to me when I paste them in a .js file in NetBeans. I have had such issues before, but the cause was somewhere above, in the same file. Can you paste all the code that goes before this one? Or perhaps move this to the beginning of the file just to see if it still says there's a problem?

Comment: Thanks. Tried moving the block up, and the offending code appears to be a string of assignments in this format:

var datatypes = ['integers', 'strings', 'zips', 'phones'];

Placing the block before this code makes the error go away.

Comment: Never mind. Answer below. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D'oh! I failed to realize that this JavaScript is being parsed by PHP and contains some PHP code prior to the object literal assignment. Apparently the JavaScript Debugger is not too happy about statements like:

```
var foo = <?php print $bar ?>;
```

Go figure. :P

Comment: if this is the answer to your question, you should mark your own answer as accepted with the green tick! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I did a quick test in my netbeans 6.9, and i did not get any warnings or errors. You should probably try and install the "Web Applications" plugin and see. Which version are you using?